How to safely tell if a film roll has been developed?
I found an old Kodak Plus-X film roll (from the late 1950s - early 1960s) in a metal canister, wrapped in paper. I expect the roll to have been developed but I want to be sure before exposing it to direct light and potentially ruining an undeveloped roll.
Is there a safe way I could use to check that this roll has been developed (different from exposed or not)? Is it safe to use indirect red LED light?

I have never seen a developed film kept in a roll, always seen these handled as flat strips.

35mm? Is the leader sticking out of the canister, or has it been wound back into it? It's not a certain method, so I've not posted this as an answer, but I've always wound the film all the way back into the canister after exposure and before processing. If the leader is sticking out, does it look like it's been folded at the end? Might tell you whether it's been in a camera.

I don't know the conventions of the 50s/60s - I wasn't around - but I've had full rolls of developed film returned to me uncut - there are various reasons for this. Again, I'm not familiar with film canisters of the 50s/60s, but I wonder if it's possible that a developed, uncut roll could conceivably be put back into a canister for storage. I wouldn't rule it out. fyi @xenoid

The film has no cassette. It is a coil of 135 film. I believe it predates the 35mm cassettes.

@osullic 35mm film tends to curl in a very annoying fashion if kept tightly curled like that.  The more flexible film base that let it be rolled-back into the canister was one of the features of APS film.  I think I too have received 35mm film rolled into the plastic outer can, but not from any lab I'd call good.

@davolfman my point is just that all kinds of things are possible. Someone finding old film… yes, it's possible that the original photographer put developed film back in a canister for some reason. That's all I'm saying. In my case, I use a Noblex camera - exposing frames measuring 24mm x 66mm. Sometimes if I've shot particularly dark scenes, or had to unload/reload the film mid-roll for whatever reason (messing up frame spacing), I'll ask the lab not to cut the film and send it back to me as one long roll. It is precisely good labs who will happily do this kind of thing for their customers.

20 years ago, I tried a budget lab and they returned film to me where they cut right through some frames. Now that was a bad lab! I guess by offering a cheaper service, they were under time pressure and paid much less attention to what they were doing. I didn't need to learn that lesson a second time.

Kodak Plus-X film is a “panchromatic” black-and-white negative film. The prefix “pan-” is Greek, meaning “all”. “Panchromatic” film translates as “sensitive to all colors”—no safelight to be used. Two exceptions—an infrared darkroom viewing scope can be used as well as a dim green safelight placed some distance from the film.
Such viewing systems could reveal if the film has been developed or not. No practical way to discover if undeveloped film has ever been exposed in a camera.
A darkroom worker, experienced at handling and processing black-and-white film could take the film, in its present metal canister, and develop it. Such treatment, if properly performed, is unlikely to harm film that was previously exposed and developed. This film, after development or redevelopment, will display images provided it has not been spoiled by adverse treatment.
With over 50 years of photofinisher experience, I know what I am talking about.

A much better answer than mine! Thanks Alan

Orthochromatic film is not particularly sensitive to red light wavelengths, and so in theory orthochromatic film can be examined under a red light. Developed film should show discernable pictures, but of course the latent image in undeveloped film is not a visible image, so that would be the identifier between developed/undeveloped. However, I think that Kodak PLUS-X films have always been panchromatic - sensitive to all wavelengths of visible light - and so exposing to red light would fog/expose/ruin an undeveloped roll no differently to daylight really.
There is always the possibility of doing a "clip test" where you clip off part of the film in complete darkness and see what you get. You could try developing it, or you could just look at it to see if it's developed already. You may cut through an exposure, but at least you don't ruin the entire roll doing this. This brings a new question to my mind though... what happens if you put already-developed film back through a developer? I don't know.
It should obviously be stated that I have no direct experience of this, so definitely take more advice than just mine!

If developed negatives have been properly "fixed", redeveloping it should not affect the film at all. That's why fixer is called fixer. It fixes (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fix) the image so it can not be further altered by standard developing chemicals. Of course nothing is permanent. UV light will cause negatives to fade over time. Some chemicals not normally used in development can chemically alter a developed negative, such as Kodak IN-5 Intensifier that Ansel Adams famously used on the lower half of the 'Moonrise, Hernandez, NM' negative years after he had developed it.
